# Need every time client id and client secret for access token in django?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I am following the below link to learn about oauth authentication

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html

Do i need to give client id and client secret code to access those api?
if yes, how can i access from front end? please help to findout.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

to access to the secured API you need to give client id and client secret of your application.